# how to include boost headers in own header-only library

Tags: c++, interface, cmake, header-only

i am using Jetbrains CLion 2017.3 and the bundled CMake version 3.9.6 with mingw64 5.0 version/g++ 7.1.
Although reading the "Mastering CMake" ( i am new to CMake !) i have many difficulties to understand the basics. Since 3 days i am searching for a CMake solution to create a own header-only library that uses the boost (1.66.0 ) libraries.

Using my CMakeLists.txt results in finding the boost libraries, but i cannot include boost headers in a header file from my current source directory.

My current source diretory contains the "CMakeLists.txt" and the header file
"test_boost.h".
If i try to include boost headers in the header file "test_boost.h", boost headers cannot be found !

What i am doing wrong ?

My CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(headerOnlyLib1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(ENV{BOOST_ROOT} "C:/dev/boost/mingw/boost_1_66_0/boost")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) # only find static libs
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(BOOST 1.66 REQUIRED)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "BOOST FOUND !")
ELSE()
    message(STATUS "BOOST NOT Found !")
endif()
add_library(headerOnlyLib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(headerOnlyLib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_include_directories(headerOnlyLib INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(headerOnlyLib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I think it should be `set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/dev/boost/mingw/boost_1_66_0")`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You *can't*.

A "header-only library" is just that, one or more headers, *only*. It's not something that is linked or really stand-alone.

If your header-only library have dependencies, then the users of your library *also* have those dependencies and need to include them in their own build.

Comment: i think your answer means that,in the case of header-only libraries, the are no binaries involved. That i have understood. But is there no possibility in CMake to include other library header files ( here boost header files) in own header files belonging to the own header-only library?

Comment: @user3664264 No that's not really how header file works. Well you *can* use the preprocessor on your header file, which will create a really big header file that includes all headers you include. It's usually not a good idea, since your code becomes obfuscated and hard to find. It might also be problem with licensing. So really, distribute your library as a standalone set of header files, then have Boost as an explicit dependency that others need to use.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. i think now i have understood your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can, but you need to be more specific in defining your `boost` dependencies.

For example, the `CMakeLists.txt` file [here](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib)  depends upon `boost::system` for `boost::asio`. The dependency is defined as follows:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  # Boost::asio is header only but it requires Boost::system
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Boost::system)
.
.
.
endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

In your case, the target is `Boost::boost` for header-only dependencies, see [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html). So the relevant part becomes:

```
find_package(Boost 1.66 REQUIRED COMPONENTS boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "BOOST FOUND !")
    target_include_directories(headerOnlyLib INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
ELSE()
    message(STATUS "BOOST NOT Found !")
endif()
```

I recommend watching Daniel Pfeifer's talk at [C++ Now 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk&t=2s) for more information.
A lot has changed since "Mastering CMake" was written...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal CMake example to include header-only [BOOST PropertyTree](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.propertytree) library

- `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
set(PROJECT_NAME test)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Boost 1.82 REQUIRED)
include_directories("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "src/main.cpp")
```

- `src/main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::property_tree::ptree root;
  root.put("A", "B");
}
```

- Compile with

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```